# Gulp уведомление об компиляции

Tags: gulp

Подскажите как настроить gulp, чтобы при компиляции было уведомление в MacOS?

Что проект успешно скомпилирован или нет.

```
            const fileswatch = "html,htm,txt,json,md";
            const baseUrlSrs = "dev/src"
            const baseUrlDist = "dev/assets"
            import pkg from "gulp";

            const {gulp, src, dest, parallel, series, watch} = pkg;
            import browserSync from "browser-sync";
            import bssi from "browsersync-ssi";
            import ssi from "ssi";
            import webpackStream from "webpack-stream";
            import webpack from "webpack";
            import TerserPlugin from "terser-webpack-plugin";
            import gulpSass from "gulp-sass";
            import dartSass from "sass";
            import sassglob from "gulp-sass-glob";
            import webp from "gulp-webp";
            import gulpif from "gulp-if";

            const sass = gulpSass(dartSass);
            import postCss from "gulp-postcss";
            import cssnano from "cssnano";
            import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";
            import imagemin from "gulp-imagemin";
            import changed from "gulp-changed";
            import concat from "gulp-concat";
            import smartgrid from "smart-grid";
            import rsync from "gulp-rsync";
            import del from "del";
            import sourcemaps from "gulp-sourcemaps"

            let param = '--dev'//--build

            console.log(process.argv[3])
            if (process.argv[3] === '--dev' || process.argv[3] === '--build') {
                param = process.argv[3];
            }


            async function cleandist() {
                del("app/**/*", {force: true});
            }

            async function buildhtml() {
                let includes = new ssi("dev/", "app/", "/**/*.html");
                includes.compile();
                del("app/parts", {force: true});
                del("app/src", {force: true});
            }

            function buildcopy() {
                return src(
                    [
                        `dev/**/*`,
                        `!dev/src/**/*`,

                    ],
                    {base: "dev/"}
                ).pipe(dest("app"));
            }


            function browsersync() {
                browserSync.init({
                    server: {
                        baseDir: "dev/",
                        middleware: bssi({baseDir: "dev/", ext: ".html"}),
                    },
                    ghostMode: {clicks: false},
                    notify: false,
                    online: true,
                    // tunnel: 'yousutename', // Attempt to use the URL https://yousutename.loca.lt
                });
            }


            function scripts() {
                // let plugins = {};
                let optionMode;
                let optionDefault = {
                    performance: {hints: false},
                    // plugins: [plugins],
                    module: {
                        rules: [
                            {
                                test: /\.m?js$/,
                                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                                use: {
                                    loader: "babel-loader",
                                    options: {
                                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                                        plugins: ["babel-plugin-root-import", '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'],
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    optimization: {
                        minimize: true,
                        minimizer: [
                            new TerserPlugin({
                                terserOptions: {format: {comments: false}},
                                extractComments: false,
                            }),
                        ],
                    }
                };
                switch (param) {
                    case '--dev':
                        optionMode = {
                            mode: 'development',
                        }
                        break;
                    case '--build':
                        optionMode = {
                            mode: 'production',
                        }
                }
                let option = Object.assign({}, optionMode, optionDefault);
                return src([`${baseUrlSrs}/js/app.js`])
                    .pipe(webpackStream(option, webpack))
                    .pipe(concat("app.min.js"))
                    .pipe(dest(`${baseUrlDist}`))
                    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
            }

            function styles() {
                let is_dev;
                switch (param) {
                    case '--dev':
                        is_dev = true;
                        break;
                    case '--build':
                        is_dev = false;
                }
                return src([
                    `${baseUrlSrs}/styles/*.*`,
                    `!${baseUrlSrs}/styles/css/**/*`,
                    `!${baseUrlSrs}/styles/_*.*`,
                ])

                    .pipe(gulpif(is_dev, sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true})))
                    .pipe(sassglob())
                    .pipe(sass({"include css": true}))
                    .pipe(gulpif(is_dev,
                        postCss([autoprefixer({grid: "autoplace"})]),
                        postCss([autoprefixer({grid: "autoplace"}), cssnano({preset: ["default", {discardComments: {removeAll: true}}]}),
                    ])))
                    .pipe(concat("app.min.css"))
                    .pipe(gulpif(is_dev, sourcemaps.write()))
                    .pipe(dest(`${baseUrlDist}`))
                    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
            }

            function images() {
                return src([`${baseUrlSrs}/images/**/*`])
                    .pipe(changed(`${baseUrlDist}/images`))
                    .pipe(imagemin())
                    .pipe(dest(`${baseUrlDist}/images`))
                    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
            }

            function fonts() {
                return src([`${baseUrlSrs}/fonts/**/*`])
                    .pipe(changed(`${baseUrlDist}/fonts`))
                    .pipe(dest(`${baseUrlDist}/fonts`))
                    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
            }

            function images_webp() {
                return src([`${baseUrlSrs}/images/**/*`, `!${baseUrlSrs}/images/**/*.svg`])
                    .pipe(changed(`${baseUrlDist}/images`))
                    .pipe(webp())
                    .pipe(dest(`${baseUrlDist}/images`))
                    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
            }


            function startwatch() {
                watch(`${baseUrlSrs}/styles/**/*`, {usePolling: true}, styles);
                watch(`${baseUrlSrs}/js/**/*`, {usePolling: true}, scripts);
                watch(`${baseUrlSrs}/images/**/*`, {usePolling: true}, parallel(images, images_webp));
                watch(`${baseUrlSrs}/fonts/**/*`, {usePolling: true}, fonts);
                watch(`dev/**/*.{${fileswatch}}`, {usePolling: true}).on(
                    "change",
                    browserSync.reload
                );
            }

            function deploy() {
                return src("app/").pipe(
                    rsync({
                        root: "app/",
                        hostname: "username@yousite.com",
                        destination: "yousite/public_html/",
                        // clean: true, // Mirror copy with file deletion
                        include: [
                            /* '*.htaccess' */
                        ], // Included files to deploy,
                        exclude: ["**/Thumbs.db", "**/*.DS_Store"],
                        recursive: true,
                        archive: true,
                        silent: false,
                        compress: true,
                    })
                );
            }


            function smartGrid(done) {
                let settings = {
                    filename: '_smartGrid',
                    outputStyle: "sСЃss" /* less || scss || sass || styl */,
                    columns: 60 /* number of grid columns */,
                    offset: "10px" /* gutter width px || % || rem */,
                    mobileFirst: true /* mobileFirst ? 'min-width' : 'max-width' */,
                    container: {
                        maxWidth: "100%" /* max-width Рѕn very large screen */,
                        fields: "10px",
                    },
                    breakPoints: {
                        lg: {
                            width: "1280px",
                            fields: "50px",
                            offset: "30px",
                        },
                        md: {
                            width: "960px",
                            fields: "30px",
                            offset: "20px",
                        },
                        sm: {
                            width: "600px",
                        },
                        xs: {
                            width: "450px",
                        },
                    },
                };
                smartgrid(`${baseUrlSrs}/styles/`, settings);
                done();
            }


            export {scripts, styles, images, images_webp, smartGrid, fonts, deploy};
            export let assets = series(scripts, styles, parallel(images, images_webp,));
            export default series((done) => {
                    param = '--dev';
                    done()
                },
                scripts,
                styles,
                parallel(images, images_webp, fonts),
                parallel(browsersync, startwatch)
            );

            export let build = series(
                (done) => {
                    param = '--build';
                    done();
                },
                cleandist,
                parallel(images, images_webp, fonts),
                scripts,
                styles,
                buildcopy,
                buildhtml
            );


            //

            // export let build =
            //
            //
```